# Infinite countable set of propositional variables into CNF/DNF

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form, conjunctive-normal-form

It is known that for every finite formula, there is an
equivalent formula in CNF (conjunctive normal form) and another equivalent formula in DNF (disjunctive normal form).

But can any subset K of set of boolean funcions: P → {0, 1} (propositional formula), where P is infinite countable set of propositional variables (language) be re-written into equivalent CNF and DNF form?

Comment: The usual definitions of CNF and DNF require formulas in the usual sense, in particular formulas of finite length. Presumably, you intend some more general notions of CNF and DNF that allow infinite length (since otherwise the answer to your question is trivially no.)  What exactly are those more general notions?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I could not find any argument, why formula of infinite (and countable) number of propositional variables could not be written into equivalent form in CNF. The reason is that CNF can be defined as "a conjunction of one or more clauses, where a clause is a disjunction of literals; otherwise put, it is an AND of ORs". I see no reason why it could not be a conjunction of infinite amount of clauses.

Comment: If you're allowing a conjunction of infinitely (possibly even uncountably) many clauses and also allowing each clause to be a disjunction of infinitely many literals, then why doesn't the usual construction affirmatively answer your question? To get a CNF for a given $K$, proceed as follows: For each truth-assignment $v\notin K$, form the disjunction $D_v$ of all literals falsified by $v$, and then form the conjunction of all these $D_v$'s.

Comment: @J.Vozár Neboj, nejsi jediný, kdo si s tímto úkolem neví rady. Naopak neznám nikoho, kdo by věděl, jak na to :D LR

Comment: @Speedding Len ma štve, že zatiaľ som si vždy nejako poradiť s úlohami z Diskrétky, Lingebry a aj Grafov. Aj keď som niekedy strávil niekoľko hodín hľadaním aspoň nejakej zmienky o danom probléme. Ale teraz - nič. Nemám ani potuchy, čo tam napísať.